# Write Array data built in forEach loop back to original Object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using forEach in a vuejs watcher to modify my array of objects. Goal is to have the new value (end_time) in each object at the end. allChapters already contains everything I want but I can't seem to get it written back to the original object.

```
watch: {
  episode (episode) {
    episode.chapters = episode.chapters.forEach((chapter, index, allChapters) => {
      let endTime = ''
      if (allChapters[(index + 1)]) {
        endTime = allChapters[(index + 1)].start_time
      } else {
        endTime = '99:99:99'
      }
      console.log(index + ': ' + chapter.start_time + ' / ' + endTime)
      allChapters[index] = {
        'start_time': chapter.start_time,
        'title': chapter.title,
        'end_time': endTime
      }
    })
  }
},
```

Comment: you should accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `forEach` does not return anything, so you end up assigning `undefined` to the `episode.chapters`.

Either remove the `episode.chapters =`

```
episode (episode) {
    episode.chapters.forEach((chapter, index, allChapters) => { ... })
```

or use `map` which returns a new array

```
watch: {
  episode (episode) {
    episode.chapters = episode.chapters.map((chapter, index, allChapters) => {
      let endTime = ''
      if (allChapters[(index + 1)]) {
        endTime = allChapters[(index + 1)].start_time
      } else {
        endTime = '99:99:99'
      }
      console.log(index + ': ' + chapter.start_time + ' / ' + endTime)

      return {...chapter, 'end_time': endTime};
    })
  }
},
```

Comment: looks like I didn't see the obvious one. Thanks for helping out.